# Pip: unistall ALL pkgs installed during `-e` installation

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I just installed a github repo with `-e .`; That's what I intended to do, only I didn't notice I was in my `base` conda env rather than in the intended environment.

That package, in turn, installed a sh*tload of dependencies (like something north of ~20 Gb). Now, I'm in need of uninstalling all that stuff. Is there a way to tell `pip` to do that without breaking my conda `base` env?
I was thinking.. Is there a log of installed pkgs *with timestamps` so that I can tell pip to remove all the stuff installed from a certain date onwards?

Comment: does `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt` help?

Comment: Aside: This kind of problem doesn't happen if you're using something like [poetry2nix](https://github.com/nix-community/poetry2nix); in the Nix world, everything that's built is hash-addressed and immutable (so you can't change which packages are installed to an environment -- instead, next time you try to enter a given environment it gets built from scratch if there you don't have an instance prebuilt with the exact same hash, where the hash is derived from the dependencies, _their_ dependencies, &c down the tree).

Comment: @frunkad: `requirements.txt` is what I looked into expecting to find a long list of deps. There is nothing there. 
@CharlesDuffy: thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such record, unless you invoked pip with file logging or still have the terminal scrollback available.

You could check the times of the site-packages subdirectories, for example if pip has installed `foo==1.0` then you will find a file like:

```
/path/to/installenv/lib/python3.XY/site-packages/foo-1.0.dist-info/INSTALLER
```

The mtime of this file should be the install time.

However, this method is not 100% reliable because it is possible that pip needed to *upgrade* a dependency which was already installed, in which case uninstalling it completely would leave an unsatisfied dependency in your env. You would need to downgrade to what was there previously, and that information is only in the pip log (which is only logged to terminal by default).

My recommendation is to destroy and recreate your conda base env.

Comment: <My recommendation is to destroy and recreate your conda base env.> I see. Can I do it without compromising the *other* conda environments?